# How to use codeigniter form validation library for two different languages at the same time?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I'm trying to use codeigniter form validation library for showing two different lines in two different languages at the same time but it throws an error:

```
$this -> form_validation -> set_message('required', 'Warning %s should not be empty! <br /> Dikkat %s alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır.');
```

Is there a way to using that function like this without facing that error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: sprintf(): Too few arguments

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 525
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sprintf() function on line 525 in core/libraries/form_validation.php only has two arguments.

```
$message = sprintf($line, $this->_translate_fieldname($row['label']));
```

The first argument must be a string with designated insertion points. The following arguments (in a sprintf function) will have to match the number of insertion points. And codeigniter only uses one.

From the Codeigniter Userguide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

`If you include %s in your error string, it will be replaced with the "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.`

But, the solution for your problem is this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Warning %1$s should not be empty! <br /> Dikkat %1$s alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır.');
```

%1$s represents the first argument after the string argument in sprintf(). It is explained very well in the examples here: https://www.php.net/sprintf

Comment: i have used your suggestion but error is still same.A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: sprintf(): Too few arguments

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 525

Comment: Aha %2$s wasn't working but %1$s is working perfect! How did you come up with this ? What's the logic behind that ? I'm very curios

Comment: motto: I have edited the answer with a link to the php manual. The examples explains it very well.